# ChoiceList as service possible?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have the following code:

```
namespace Acme\Demo\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList;

class MyChoiceList extends LazyChoiceList
{
    protected function loadChoiceList()
    {
        return SimpleChoiceList(array('t'=>'test'));
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```
SMyChoiceList:
    class: Acme\Demo\Form\MyChoiceList;
```

Then when I try to do:

```
$builder
    ->add('mychoice', 'choice', array('choice_list' => 'SMyChoiceList'
    ));
```

I get:

`The option "choice_list" with value "SMyChoiceList" is expected to be of type "null", "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface"`

`LazyChoiceList` already implements `ChoiceListInterface`... so I'm guessing Symfony2 `choice_list` parameter doesn't support services or am I missing something?

I assumed it worked similar to http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#form-cookbook-form-field-service

But I guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ..

```
'choice_list' => 'SMyChoiceList'
```

.. you are just using a string.

You can call it directly using ..

```
'choice_list' => new MyChoiceList()
```

Or if it has dependents you can inject it into your form constructor like..

```
your.form:
    class: %your.form.class%
    arguments:
        - @SMyChoiceList
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: your_form_alias }
```

.. and then use it in your form like..

```
protected $choiceList;

public function __construct(ChoiceListInterface $choiceList)
{
    $this->choiceList = $choiceList;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('mychoice', 'choice', array(
            'choice_list' => $this->choiceList,
        ))
    ;
}
```

**UPDATE**

To use your choice list in a custom form type you would do the following (using the same services set up as above)...

```
protected $choiceList;

public function __construct(ChoiceListInterface $choiceList)
{
    $this->choiceList = $choiceList;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'choice_list' => $this->choiceList,
    ));
}

public function getParent()
{
    return 'choice';
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'your_form_alias';
}
```

Which you could then use instead of choice, like...

```
$builder
    ->add('something', 'your_form_alias', array(
        // Your choice options (expanded, label, attr, etc)
    ))
;
```

It's all in the page that you added before, more specifically http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#defining-the-field-type

Comment: Yes, I'm aware it's a string. However I thought it'd work similar to: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#form-cookbook-form-field-service . Maybe I should suggest it as an enhancement... Thanks by the way.

Comment: If you wanted to create a choice field with that as a choice list you would need to inject the choice list into your form and use it in the same way as the in the link that you posted. Then you could call it as the field type rather than choice.

Comment: Wait, hang on. Can you show me what you mean? I'm not sure I follow completely.

Comment: I've added a better explanation to my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. So another form type to 'wrap' the choice eh? Hmm. Seems a bit of a workaround but I guess that's the only way to make it into a 'service'. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I tried doing this but I get `You cannot add children to a simple form. Maybe you should set the option "compound" to true?`

Comment: It might be better to ask this in another question with more information about your specific problem as the details above are quite vague.